# Prestashop module development - why is this template redirecting not working

Tags: content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

On user-registration confirmation I want to show a simple popup. For the moment, in order to simplify I'm happy to show an "Hello World".

This is the template file, views/templates/hook/**registrationConfirm.tpl**

```
<div id="idname" class="block">
   <h1 class="title_block">HelloWorld</h1>
</div>
```

In my custom module I have this hook (which I know is being triggered doing debug):

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params) {
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'registrationConfirm.tpl');
}
```

It doesn't show anything (I also tried inspect the source code of the rendered page, but I dind't find the "HelloWorld")

Answer (score 3):

Hooks starting by "Action" react to an action but do not display anything, but those starting with "Display" do.

You should also react to the hook displayCustomerAccount

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd() {
    $this->is_new_account = true;
}

public function hookDisplayCustomerAccount()
{
    if ($this->is_new_account) {
        return $this->display(__FILE__, 'registrationConfirm.tpl');
    }
}
```

Comment: What does  '$this' contains? And how can I be sure that in the real case, when the website is being visited by thousands of people, the 'is_new_account' values aren't mixed?

Comment: in a module context, `$this` is the current module http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
`$this->is_new_account` is only set for the current execution, if the same (or an other) visitor runs the same script at the same moment (or at an other moment), he will have an other `$this->is_new_account`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm wandering why it's not working. Is this supported in PS 1.6 ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution posted by @shagshag but for some reason it doesn't work for me. So I share my solution (it's not pretty, nor efficient I think, but it seem to work for me): in the **hookActionCustomerAccountAdd** I save on a custom table (newCustomersTmp) email and customer id, because these are the data I need after, in the display Hook. Then in the **hookDisplayCustomerAccount** I check if an user with the current email ($this->context->customer->email) already exists in my table: if so I retrieve the data, do the actions I need with them and delete the row in the table.